# Unable to clone class object

Tags: c#, clone

Here is a case for which cloning of object fails:

```
[Serializable]
public class MasterClass
{
    public MasterClass(DataRow row)
    {
        EntityData = row;
    }

    public DataRow EntityData
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

for cloning I am using extention method(`Clone()`) from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects-in-c-sharp):

while cloning `MasterClass` object following error message thrown at runtime:

> Type 'System.Data.DataRow' in Assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

Any solution how to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a parameterless constructor:

```
public MasterClass()
{
}
```

---

**Converting `DataRow`**

Assuming you `DataRow` has a `Table`:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyKeyValue {
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}


[Serializable]
public class MasterClass
{
    public MasterClass() {}

    public MasterClass(DataRow row)
    {
        var list = new List<MyKeyValue>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in row.Table.Columns)
        {
            list.Add(new MyKeyValue{Key = col.ColumnName, Value = Convert.ToString(row[col.ColumnName])});
        }
        EntityData = list;
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyKeyValue> EntityData
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not that class it is that the prop must be serializable.

Comment: Constructor having `DataRow` parameter is must constructor to boot class object. Any other solution?

Comment: You can have two constructors. But you also need to convert the `DataRow` to something serializable.

Comment: Any way to convert `DataRow` into `serializable` object?

Comment: See my edit, it stores the `DataRow` as a Serializable list of object  `MyKeyValue`. All values are however converted from `object` to `string`.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are using the DataRow for, you will likely have to parse the values into a custom class that is serializable.

Comment: Is there easy way to do this rather than converting `DataRow` into custom serializable class?

Comment: I like Robert Fricke's answer (post-edit).  It is the classiest with least amount of work.  Just remember to convert your values when using them back to what they need to be.

Answer (score 1):

You must implement [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface - for serialization, and add constructor that takes (SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) - for deserialization.